# Conditional value output in QGIS field calculator for array aggregation

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression

I have a three point across x with five repeating rows with this attributes:

```
[ 2, 1, 1 ]
[ 1, 2, 2 ]
[ 1, 1, 1 ]
[ 2, 2, 2 ]
[ 4, 4, 4 ]
```

I want to calculate a new field which aggregates the rows, currently I have:  `array_min(array_agg( "collumn", group_by:="row" ))`

This will compute this result:

```
[ 2, 1, 1 ] -> 1
[ 2, 2, 2 ] -> 2
[ 1, 1, 1 ] -> 1
[ 2, 2, 2 ] -> 2
[ 4, 4, 4 ] -> 4
```

What I'm aiming to do next is to do a conditional where if the row aggregates is lower than the previous row aggregates, use that lower value instead of the computed value.

```
[ 2, 1, 1 ] -> 1: OK
[ 2, 2, 2 ] -> 2: OK
[ 1, 1, 1 ] -> 1: Lower than previous, use previous
[ 2, 2, 2 ] -> 2: OK
[ 4, 4, 4 ] -> 4: OK
```

I'm constrained on only using QGIS field calculator. Temporary field is allowed. What are my options?

Comment: Do you have a row number to sort data or do you rely on the data creation order ?

Comment: @J.R I have row number inherited from creation order, it should be sequential

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```sql
if(
    array_min(array("a","b","c"))
    <
    array_min(
        array(
            attribute(get_feature_by_id(@layer,$id-1), 'a'),
            attribute(get_feature_by_id(@layer,$id-1), 'b'),
            attribute(get_feature_by_id(@layer,$id-1), 'c')
            )
        )
    ,
    array_min(
        array(
            attribute(get_feature_by_id(@layer,$id-1), 'a'),
            attribute(get_feature_by_id(@layer,$id-1), 'b'),
            attribute(get_feature_by_id(@layer,$id-1), 'c')
            )
        )
    ,
    array_min(array("a","b","c"))
    )
```

*Note* that depending on your exact requirements you may want to use `get_feature()` instead of `get_feature_by_id()`. In my example no gaps in the id's are allowed.